# jQuery on click of button show and hide closest divs

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Hi I am using masonry with laravel and I am basically loading my blogs into a masonry layout. I have an abstract which i output as well as all the content, the content is hidden by default by css. I have a read more button once clicked adds a class to that div which expands the masonry block.

I also want to hide the abstract within this masonry block but I can't seem to be able to do this successfully, instead I am hiding all the abstracts on the page. I've tried using selectors such as parent and children but I don't think I am quite getting the concept here. Any have any ideas as to how I can hide the class div.abstract and show div.fullstroy when I click div.button #read-more ??

A simple version of my code is below or please view my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2n0bunty/)

Any help much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="masonary-blogs">
    <div class="one-third column">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div class="abstract">
            <p>abstract</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fullstory">
            <p>fullstory</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#" id="read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
       <div class="one-third column">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div class="abstract">
            <p>abstract</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fullstory">
            <p>fullstory</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#" id="read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div class="abstract">
            <p>abstract</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fullstory">
            <p>fullstory</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#" id="read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one-third {
    width:23%;
    background:#dedede;
    min-height:100px;

}
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.fullstory {
    display:none;
}
.gigante {
    width:100%;
}
.hide {
    display:none;
}

.show {
    display:block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#masonary-blogs').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    var blogItem = $(this).parents('.one-third'),
        container = $('#masonary-blogs');

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Blog link click');

    $('.gigante').removeClass('gigante');
    $(e.target).parents('.one-third').addClass('gigante');
    $('.one-third').children('.abstract').hide();

});
```

Comment: Have you tried the JQuery closest() function? 

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @KyleT yes i did, i tried this `$('.one-third').closest('.abstract').hide();` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the .abstract div is a sibling not a parent or child to the button so it would be

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).siblings('div.abstract').hide();
})
```

edit:
or if you want to show the full story and hide the abstract it could be something like

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).siblings('div').toggle();
})
```

Comment: ahh yes thanks. I incoporated the above with my existing code to come up with this.. `$(e.target).parents().siblings('div.abstract').hide();
$(e.target).parents().siblings('div.content').show();` and it works so thanks!

Comment: using toggle() instead of hide or show will eliminate some of your
code keeping it DRY

Comment: you mean like so? `$(e.target).parents().siblings('div.content').toggle();` I have another problem, when I click on the next read more I want to hide the last div.fullstory and show the last div.abstract. how can I do that? which selector would I use?

Comment: ahh yes much cleaner!